# SQL SERVER DUPLICATE VALUES

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables, one for courses names (named `Courses`) and one for universities that teach the course (named `Unicourses`).

I want to select all the columns from `UniCourses` and also `coursename` column from `Courses` table.

Everything goes well but I have repeated values in the query result, and I want all `coursename` column to be unique.

I tried using DISTINCT but I can't manage to make it work.

this is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT 
    UniCourses.courseid, UniCourses.uniname, 
    UniCourses.rating, UniCourses.ratingppl, 
    UniCourses.approved,
    Courses.courseid, Courses.coursename  
FROM 
    UniCourses 
INNER JOIN 
    Courses ON UniCourses.courseid = Courses.courseid  
WHERE 
    UniCourses.approved = 1  
ORDER BY 
    UniCourses.rating / CASE UniCourses.ratingppl WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE UniCourses.ratingppl END DESC;
```

This is what I get

```
|courseid|uniname|rating|ratingppl|approved|coursename|
_______________________________________________________
|    4   |howard | 20   |    5    |    1   |  algebra |
|    4   |hampton| 10   |    2    |    1   |  algebra |
```

this is what I want

```
|courseid|uniname|rating|ratingppl|approved|coursename|
_______________________________________________________
|    4   |hampton| 10   |    2    |    1   |  algebra |
```

As you can see, these are the same course that 2 universities teach, 
I want only 1 to appear, that has the highest rating which is calculated by 
( rating / ratingppl );

`Courses` table columns:

```
courseid, coursename
```

`Unicourses` table columns:

```
courseid, uniname, rating, ratingppl, approved
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH X AS 
 (
    SELECT UniCourses.courseid,UniCourses.uniname,UniCourses.rating
          ,UniCourses.ratingppl,UniCourses.approved,Courses.courseid
          ,Courses.coursename  
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Courses.coursename
                              ORDER BY ISNULL((rating / NULLIF(ratingppl, 0)),0)
                               DESC) rnRating
    FROM UniCourses 
    INNER JOIN Courses 
    ON UniCourses.courseid = Courses.courseid  
    WHERE UniCourses.approved=1
 )
SELECT courseid,uniname,rating ,ratingppl
      ,approved,courseid ,coursename
FROM x
WHERE rnRating = 1
```

Comment: Well, it definitely works, I don't really know how or why, but I guess I"ll have to figure it out alone. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do your join on courseid when both howard and hampton have the same courseid.

Change howard courseid to a different value and it'll return your unique record.

Comment: If you can only connect them by courseid then you should either have unique courseid's for every uniname, or you should include the uniname on the courses table and do your join based off of courseid and uniname.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no Id coulmns

```
SELECT
    UniCourses.courseid,
    UniCourses.uniname,
    UniCourses.rating,
    UniCourses.ratingppl,
    UniCourses.approved,
    Courses.courseid,
    Courses.coursename  
FROM UniCourses 
INNER JOIN Courses ON 
        Courses.courseid = UniCourses.courseid
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        UniCourses.courseid, 
        MAX(UniCourses.rating / CASE UniCourses.ratingppl WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE UniCourses.ratingppl END) as MaxValue
    FROM UniCourses
    GROUP BY UniCourses.courseid
    ) AS CoursesMax ON 
            CoursesMax.courseid = UniCourses.courseid 
            AND (UniCourses.rating / CASE UniCourses.ratingppl WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE UniCourses.ratingppl END)= MaxValue
```